# Timelock Transactions

Tags: locktime

I would like to know if timelock transactions are considered standard with the current bitcoin client. If the answer is no, this means that you should use a different client or is it up to user choice?
Furthermore, if someone wants to construct such a transaction which is the structure it should have?

Comment: do you mean the locktime field in the transaction or OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY?

Comment: Both I would say. nlocktime field is used to lock the transaction in the future and then how it will be verified?

Comment: i wrote [this](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/40784/2116) to explain how locktime and OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nLocktime` has always been standard and is used to prevent [fee sniping](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/2340).

`OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY` is currently not implemented and is not enforced.

A non-standard transaction can be mined by a miner, but will not relay around the normal peer to peer network. A transaction who has a `nLockTime` which has not been passed is *invalid*, and won't be relayed or included in a block until this time has passed.

Comment: [Also related to fee sniping.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6216)

Comment: So if my understanding is correct nLickTime is another parameter which defines when the current transaction will enter the blockchain.
On the other hand, OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY is a script which gives us the ability to enter the transaction in the blockchain but to block the funds until a certain timestamp or block height.

Comment: A minimum time or block height before which a transaction is invalid, yes.