# Is it possible to schedule a transaction in the future?

Tags: locktime

Wondering if it's technically possible to set up a transaction to be sent in the future, for example 6 months? Is this related to block timestamps parameters? Transaction timestamps?

Comment: Who will keep your transaction. For what?

Comment: I would like to put some funds in the blockchain so I'm sure I will not spend it. Also I'm curious about this. Sorry newbie here.

Comment: @Theodore.us, you may want to look at OP_CHECKLOCKTIMEVERIFY for that usecase. It lets you make a transaction output which can't be spent until a time in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is `tx.nLockTime`. A transaction mined before its nLockTime is invalid, so you can send your funds to yourself on some newly created address, then send it back with a locktime and destroy the private key for the newly created address.  Transactions with nLockTime can be amended, but since you destroyed the private key, you actually can't, thus preventing them from being spent before that time has passed.

See [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/40706/why-is-op-checklocktimeverify-disabled-by-maximum-sequence-number/40784#40784), [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=321550.0), or [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/31fzh5/nlocktime/).

Note that nLockTime transactions may not be stored/relayed by the network. So you need to keep the transaction in a safe place and broadcast it at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik it's not possible.

But you can ask a relative to help and make with him 2-2 multisignature transaction so you will be sure you will not spend money until you have two sigs.